# Scala subproject getting code coverage for outer project

Tags: scala, sbt, code-coverage

I have a project structure similar to the diagram below. The `Bar` project is my test code. I was wondering if I could get some code coverage against the `src/main` code FROM the Bar project code?

```
|-- Bar
|   |-- build.sbt
|   +-- src
|       |-- main
|       |   |-- java
|       |   |-- resources
|       |   +-- scala
|       |       +-- Bar.scala
|       +-- test
|           |-- java
|           +-- resources
|-- build.sbt
|-- project
|   |-- Build.scala
|
+-- src
    |-- main
    |   |-- java
    |   |-- resources
    |   +-- scala
    |       +-- Hello.scala
    +-- test
        |-- java
        |-- resources
        +-- scala
            +-- HelloTest.scala
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Bar project relies on methods in the src/main your Bar tests will cover them both